# mysql count() with two tables and don't repeat more than 2 row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.

1. **Table: employees**

[image]

2. **Table: employee_roles**

[image]

I'd like to show a list of all employees where they don't have more than 2 or equal employee_id.
I mean something like this I need to show:

[image]

How can I do the query? I used this query but it doesn't work. Also with the conditional WHERE name like '%'.

```
SELECT COUNT(id_employee), name 
FROM employees
WHERE name LIKE '%' AND id_employee NOT IN
(SELECT employee_id
FROM employee_roles);
```

Comment: `LIKE '%'` matches everything.

Comment: You need `GROUP BY name`

Comment: Don't post images, post text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want employees with one role, then you can use aggregation:

```
select id_employee
from employee_roles
group by id_employee
having count(*) = 1;
```

If you want employees with 0 or 1 role, then you need to bring in the employees with no roles, using a `left join`:

```
select e.id_employee, e.name
from employees e left join
     employee_roles er
     on e.id_employee = er.id_employee
group by e.id_employee, e.name
having count(er.id_employee) <= 1;
```

If you want to count them, use a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from (select e.id_employee, e.name
      from employees e left join
           employee_roles er
           on e.id_employee = er.id_employee
      group by e.id_employee, e.name
      having count(er.id_employee) <= 1
     ) e
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

first option using `left join`

```
select
    name
from
(
    select 
      id_employee, 
      name
  from employees e 
  left join employee_roles er
  on e.id_employee = er.employee_id
  group by 
      id_employee, 
      name
  having count(employee_id) <= 1
) val
```

Second option usin `union all`

```
select
    name
from employees e
where not exists (
    select 
        employee_id
    from employee_roles er
    where e.id_employee = er.employee_id
)

union all

select
    name
from employee_roles er
join employees e
on e.id_employee = er.employee_id
group by 
    name
having count(employee_id) = 1
```

output:

```
| name  |
| ----- |
| Poul  |
| Erick |
| Joy   |
| Smith |
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the tables, then use `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY`. Then you can check if the count is `1` to filter out employees with multiple roles.

```
SELECT name
FROM employees AS e
JOIN employee_roles AS r ON e.id_employee = r.id_employee
GROUP BY e.id_employee
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```